# How can I achieve a consistent focus outline color with shadow-dom web components?

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom, lit-element

I'm using web components, mostly written with `lit-element` and `lit-html`, and they use the Shadow DOM.

Some components have buttons and other interactive parts which have the default focus outline.

When I build an app, i like to set a page-wide rule to change the focus outline to a color that clearly stands out from the page's background colors.

```
*:focus {
  outline: 2px solid lime;
}
```

i was expecting this to flow over shadow boundaries into the web components, similar to `color` and `font-size`, but it does not

considering that `outline` does not cross the shadow boundaries — what options do i have to achieve my consistent focus outline color?

Comment: Add the css code in the web components

Comment: You could just add the outline defined with a css property in your actual element, like `outline: var(--my-outline)` and just define the css property at a global level like `body  { --my-outline: 2px solid lime; }`

Comment: @AlanDávalos: yes, this is the solution, however unfortunately, this requires every component to implement ”--my-outline", and so this will make sharing and using open source components difficult unless everybody can agree on the same standardized variable name... i recommend "--focus-outline"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Standardize CSS variable `--focus-outline` in your app

application-level:

```
* {
  --focus-outline: 2px solid lime;
}

*:focus {
  outline: var(--focus-outline);
}
```

example component usage:

```
*:focus {
  outline: var(--focus-outline, 2px solid #0af);
}
```

every component must be refactored to accept this variable

each component will have to define its own fallback like `2px solid #0af` (unfortunately there is not yet any standardized `default-focus-outline` css value)

Comment: it's not a great solution, but it's the best available at the moment.. in the future, the shadow parts api will likely provide a better answer to this quandary

Comment: Hi Chase, how can we do this at the component level? (component in angular/ionic)

Comment: I simply want to set outline: none for all of the HTML elements.

Comment: @Hemang the idea is that we set css variable `--focus-outline` on the webpage, and then every web component accepts the variable via `outline: var(--focus-outline);` — and it's fine to set the webpage `--focus-outline: none;` if that's what you want for the focus behavior